# Should iOS Universal Links work over custom ports?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am trying to get iOS Universal Links to work for `https://my-domain.com:4443` (i.e. over SSL, but with a custom port number; not the conventional 443 port), but it isn't working.

I'm pretty confident I didn't do anything wrong, since my initial setup worked fine over port 443, and I simply changed the server port to 4443 to test the idea. In fact, I also added support for `applinks:my-domain.com:4443` in my Xcode project (I tried both with and without the port, without any luck).

I am asking the question, because I couldn't find anything on the subject in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW2).

Comment: Just curious, did it work when you had a link that specified https://my-domain.com:443 ? (the default SSL port, but only this time made explicit in the URL ? Have a similar issue, only my backend generates https URLs with the 443 port in the url. It only works without specifying the ports in the url

Comment: @ddewaele, In Xcode, for port 443, I only ever tried with "my-domain.com", leaving out the port number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is expected behavior.** There is nothing in the official documentation about supporting non-standard ports because non-standard ports *aren't supported*.

The only entitlement value allowed by iOS is a valid, bare domain (`applinks:my-domain.com`), which iOS will then use to check for an AASA file over SSL using the standard HTTPS port. In other words, when iOS queries either `https://my-domain.com/apple-app-site-association` or `https://my-domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`, it needs to find your AASA file without any redirects.